# how to delete create react app typescript ordering imports rule

Tags: typescript, eslint, create-react-app

I'm a newbie in `create react app typescript version` and I was wondering to ask how can I disable the ordering import :((

I've been trying to set false different attributes in both `tsconfig.json` and `tslint.json`

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must edit `tslint.json` and disable `ordered-imports` rule as follows:

```
{
    "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
    "rules": {
      "ordered-imports": false
    },
    "linterOptions": {
      "exclude": [
        "config/**/*.js",
        "node_modules/**/*.ts"
      ]
    }
}
```